# How can I make a collapsible panel in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, collapsable

Is there a way to make collapsible panels in Xamarin.Forms without purchasing it? I think, a template in a listview would not do, as the content of the panels will be different. I realize I can just make elements ivisible/visible, but if there is nothing better, I would appreciate an example that would look nice.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-accordion-user-control-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @AndroDevil Thank you for your suggestion. I am trying it now. And immediately facing a problem. I placed a StackLayout within ctrl:Accordion, and got "The property "Content" is set more than once". The accordion does have a Content inside, so I wonder how it is supposed to work...

Comment: Hi i didnt tried that solution...I just gave an idea. Just search accordion in xamarin forms...and you can find many tutorials

Comment: @AndroDevil Thank you. If you make your suggestion an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Accordion view " in xamarin.forms.  Refer this link..https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-accordion-user-control-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2):

You can use syncfusion controls, check on this free license maybe it fits for you,
[Community License](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense)

Comment: Thanks, I will check.